# mysql.user host entry with tickmarks

Tags: mysql

I noticed I have a user row in my mysql.user table where the host column has tickmarks surrounding localhost.  The rest of my entries just say localhost for host.  The tickmarks are almost like forward single quotes, which I can't seem to replicate on the keyboard and can't seem to isolate with a select statement on mysql.user

e.g. from a select user, host from mysql.user:

| dev | localhost        |
| dev | ‘localhost’

How do I remove that last entry?

Comment: A little more info - I copy/pasted the grant command from an Apple Pages doc I have, and in that doc, it has the weird tickmarks, which MySQL appears to have just replicated into the host column entry.  And help on deleting just this row, and not the valid row for dev/localhost, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the same: copy/paste this entry into your `DELETE` statement

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE host = ' ‘localhost’' 
-- value in WHERE clause copied from the resultset of your query
```

Comment: Haha!  Why didn't I think of that.  I'm staring at the select from mysql.user and the string was right there.  Thanks so much!!!!